# GNU Parallel with sequence number `{#}` and `-n` option

Tags: gnu-parallel

Using GNU Parallel 20210222 with [`--rpl '{0#} $_=sprintf("%02d",$job->seq())'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37315112/1429450) in my `~/.parallel/config`, why does

```sh
seq 256 | parallel -n 64 echo {0#}
```

output

```sh
01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02 02
03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03 03
04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04
```

and not

```sh
01
02
03
04
```

whereas

```sh
seq 256 | parallel -n 64 echo {#}
```

outputs

```sh
1
2
3
4
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hardly surprising that this:

```
seq 10 | parallel -n 5 echo '{= $_=-$_ =}'
```

gives the same as this:

```
seq 10 | parallel --rpl '{-} $_=-$_' -n 5 echo {-}
```

namely:

```
-1 -2 -3 -4 -5
-6 -7 -8 -9 -10
```

You can make {-} into a positional replacement string by prepending with the number of the argument to be replaced:

```
seq 10 | parallel --rpl '{-} $_=-$_' -n 5 echo {1-} {3-} {5-}
```

which gives:

```
-1 -3 -5
-6 -8 -10
```

The positionality can be be part of the definition:

```
seq 10 | parallel --rpl '{-} 1 $_=-$_' -n 5 echo {-}
```

which gives:

```
-1
-6
```

{#} is defined in the source code as:

```
     '{#}'  => '1 $_=$job->seq()',
```

So this is a positional replacement string and will only be replaced for the first value.

This

```
{0#} $_=sprintf("%02d",$job->seq())
```

is not a positional replacement string, but an ordinary replacement string that will be replaced for each input.

But it can easily be changed into a positional one:

```
seq 256 | parallel --rpl '{0#} 1 $_=sprintf("%02d",$job->seq())' -n 64 echo {0#}
seq 256 | parallel --rpl '{0#} $_=sprintf("%02d",$job->seq())' -n 64 echo {10#}
```

The last one looks a little confusing, but that is because we as humans will see '10' and not '1' (the input number) followed by '0#'.