# GNU Parallel job number leading zeros with multiple expansions

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I am using GNU Parallel to create a file of python jobs. I was looking to have the file look like such:

```
job_num, args
001, -a 1 -b 2
002, -a 1 -b 4
003, -a 2 -b 2
004, -a 2 -b 4
```

The idea being that each group of args can be configured at file generation while having leading zero job numbers.

Here is one thing I tried:

```
parallel --rpl '{0#} $_=sprintf("%02d",$job->seq())' echo {0#}, -a {1} -b {2} ::: 1 2 ::: 2 4
```

This results in:

```
01 01, -a 1 -b 2
02 02, -a 1 -b 4
03 03, -a 2 -b 2
04 04, -a 2 -b 4
```

The result that I did not expect was the double set of job numbers (with 3 expansions, it results in 3 job numbers). Any thoughts on how to make what I am trying work?

Tested on versions 20170322 & 20210222.

Related posts (tried the contents of each):

- [GNU Parallel with sequence number `{#}` and `-n` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665339/gnu-parallel-with-sequence-number-and-n-option)
- [Linux shell script to add leading zeros to file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672301/linux-shell-script-to-add-leading-zeros-to-file-names)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but a work-around might be `parallel 'printf -v z "%03d" {#}; echo $z -a {1} -b {2}' ::: 1 2 ::: 2 4`

Comment: Or, simpler `parallel 'printf "%03d, -a {1} -b {2}\n" {#}' ::: 1 2 ::: 2 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
parallel --rpl '{0#} 1 $f=1+int((log(total_jobs())/log(10))); $_=sprintf("%0${f}d",seq())' echo '{0#}, -a {1} -b {2}' ::: {1..9} ::: {1..12}
```

`1+int((log(total_jobs())/log(10)))` computes the width of `total_jobs()` in digits.